# How to upgrade libc version on Red Hat 8?

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux, glibc

I am running  `Red Hat Enterprise 8.2` with a libc version `glibc-2.28-189.5.el8_6.x86_64` which has a bug : [glibc causes deadlock](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1888660).

It was fixed on `glibc-2.28-206.el8`
How do I upgrade only the libc version? and make sure it is compatible with this OS?

Comment: Note: Since the first dash-separated part of the version number (`2.28`) is the same in both versions, this is just a RedHat patch level update (from `-189.5.el8_6` to `-206.el8`), and is easy and safe. Replacing the system default glibc with one whose version number differs in the first part would be a very different operation, and with RHEL it usually means an upgrade to a newer major RHEL release. In other words, if you want something newer than `glibc-2.28-*`, you would have to consider updating to RHEL 9.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `dnf` to upgrade it - `dnf update -y glibc`.

Full example from a container on my machine:

```
[root@0df679e04d17 /]# cat /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux release 8.2 (Ootpa)
[root@0df679e04d17 /]# rpm -qa glibc
glibc-2.28-101.el8.x86_64
[root@50a1768b4fcf /]# dnf update glibc
Updating Subscription Management repositories.
Unable to read consumer identity
This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You can use subscription-manager to register.
Red Hat Universal Base Image 8 (RPMs) - BaseOS                                                                                                                                       1.1 MB/s | 827 kB     00:00
Red Hat Universal Base Image 8 (RPMs) - AppStream                                                                                                                                    3.7 MB/s | 3.2 MB     00:00
Red Hat Universal Base Image 8 (RPMs) - CodeReady Builder                                                                                                                            138 kB/s |  29 kB     00:00
Dependencies resolved.
=====================================================================================================================================================================================================================
 Package                                                     Architecture                                Version                                             Repository                                         Size
=====================================================================================================================================================================================================================
Upgrading:
 glibc                                                       x86_64                                      2.28-211.el8                                        ubi-8-baseos                                      2.2 M
 glibc-common                                                x86_64                                      2.28-211.el8                                        ubi-8-baseos                                      1.0 M
 glibc-minimal-langpack                                      x86_64                                      2.28-211.el8                                        ubi-8-baseos                                       63 k
Installing weak dependencies:
 glibc-gconv-extra                                           x86_64                                      2.28-211.el8                                        ubi-8-baseos                                      1.5 M
 glibc-langpack-en                                           x86_64                                      2.28-211.el8                                        ubi-8-baseos                                      825 k

Transaction Summary
=====================================================================================================================================================================================================================
Install  2 Packages
Upgrade  3 Packages

Total download size: 5.6 M
Is this ok [y/N]: y
Downloading Packages:
(1/5): glibc-minimal-langpack-2.28-211.el8.x86_64.rpm                                                                                                                                401 kB/s |  63 kB     00:00
(2/5): glibc-langpack-en-2.28-211.el8.x86_64.rpm                                                                                                                                     2.5 MB/s | 825 kB     00:00
(3/5): glibc-common-2.28-211.el8.x86_64.rpm                                                                                                                                          1.7 MB/s | 1.0 MB     00:00
(4/5): glibc-gconv-extra-2.28-211.el8.x86_64.rpm                                                                                                                                     1.6 MB/s | 1.5 MB     00:00
(5/5): glibc-2.28-211.el8.x86_64.rpm                                                                                                                                                 1.8 MB/s | 2.2 MB     00:01
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total                                                                                                                                                                                4.0 MB/s | 5.6 MB     00:01
Running transaction check
Transaction check succeeded.
Running transaction test
Transaction test succeeded.
Running transaction
  Preparing        :                                                                                                                                                                                             1/1
  Installing       : glibc-gconv-extra-2.28-211.el8.x86_64                                                                                                                                                       1/8
  Running scriptlet: glibc-gconv-extra-2.28-211.el8.x86_64                                                                                                                                                       1/8
  Upgrading        : glibc-common-2.28-211.el8.x86_64                                                                                                                                                            2/8
  Running scriptlet: glibc-2.28-211.el8.x86_64                                                                                                                                                                   3/8
  Upgrading        : glibc-2.28-211.el8.x86_64                                                                                                                                                                   3/8
  Running scriptlet: glibc-2.28-211.el8.x86_64                                                                                                                                                                   3/8
  Installing       : glibc-langpack-en-2.28-211.el8.x86_64                                                                                                                                                       4/8
  Upgrading        : glibc-minimal-langpack-2.28-211.el8.x86_64                                                                                                                                                  5/8
  Cleanup          : glibc-minimal-langpack-2.28-101.el8.x86_64                                                                                                                                                  6/8
  Cleanup          : glibc-2.28-101.el8.x86_64                                                                                                                                                                   7/8
  Cleanup          : glibc-common-2.28-101.el8.x86_64                                                                                                                                                            8/8
  Running scriptlet: glibc-common-2.28-101.el8.x86_64                                                                                                                                                            8/8
  Running scriptlet: glibc-common-2.28-211.el8.x86_64                                                                                                                                                            8/8
  Verifying        : glibc-langpack-en-2.28-211.el8.x86_64                                                                                                                                                       1/8
  Verifying        : glibc-gconv-extra-2.28-211.el8.x86_64                                                                                                                                                       2/8
  Verifying        : glibc-minimal-langpack-2.28-211.el8.x86_64                                                                                                                                                  3/8
  Verifying        : glibc-minimal-langpack-2.28-101.el8.x86_64                                                                                                                                                  4/8
  Verifying        : glibc-2.28-211.el8.x86_64                                                                                                                                                                   5/8
  Verifying        : glibc-2.28-101.el8.x86_64                                                                                                                                                                   6/8
  Verifying        : glibc-common-2.28-211.el8.x86_64                                                                                                                                                            7/8
  Verifying        : glibc-common-2.28-101.el8.x86_64                                                                                                                                                            8/8
Installed products updated.

Upgraded:
  glibc-2.28-211.el8.x86_64                                     glibc-common-2.28-211.el8.x86_64                                     glibc-minimal-langpack-2.28-211.el8.x86_64

Installed:
  glibc-gconv-extra-2.28-211.el8.x86_64                                                                     glibc-langpack-en-2.28-211.el8.x86_64

Complete!
[root@0df679e04d17 /]# rpm -qa glibc
glibc-2.28-211.el8.x86_64
```